How to delete document with all of its fields and sub collections from Firestore using Cloud Functions
I am struggling with deleting a document with its sub collections in Firestore. I read about this issue, so I know that it's not possible to make it with one command. So I struggled with coding it for Cloud Functions using Node.js, but I am a newbie with js. Here is my code that is not working and throwing exception:

Exception from a finished function: TypeError: subcollections.forEach is not a function

const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
firebase.initializeApp();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

exports.deleteOldRounds = functions.pubsub
    .schedule("every 1 minute")
    .onRun(function(context) {
      const oneHourAgo = new Date(Date.now() - (1 * 60 * 1000));
      try {
        firestore
            .collection("Rounds")
            .where("createDate", "<", oneHourAgo)
            .get()
            .then(function(snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.empty) {
                console.log("No old rounds to delete.");
                return;
              }
              const batch = firestore.batch();
              snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                batch.delete(doc.ref);
                const subcollections = doc.ref.listCollections();
                subcollections.forEach((subcollection) => {
                  const subDocs = subcollection.listDocuments();
                  subDocs.forEach((subDoc) => {
                    batch.delete(subDoc);
                  });
                });
              });
              return batch.commit();
            });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error deleting old rounds:", error);
      }
      return null;
    });

Thank you in advance.

Your function must return a promise that resolves only after all other promises from other async work are resolved.  You can't just return null - the system will shut down your code before it finishes.  Also, listCollections and listDocuments both return a promise, not something that can be iterated with forEach.

Okay then... So how can I actually loop through my sub collections and then sub documents in order to delete them?
